# KML refresh in GoogleMaps using refresh interval

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am working with a NOAA KML layer in GoogleMaps to provide current weather data from NOAA weather buoys which update hourly.  The KML layer is about 15 hours behind due to Google cache. Looking at the GoogleMaps documentation,

```
 <refreshInterval>
```

is partially supported.

My KML layer is rather simple so my question is can I use the ***refreshInterval*** to set my KML to refresh hourly?  Searching through StackOverflow has provided other options but I'm not certain which one will function.  If ***refreshInterval*** is not appropriate in this scenario, will

```
var URL = '[your kml url here]&ver=' + Date.now();'
```

work?  If so, where should I place it in my script?

Here is my script

```
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: 'satellite',
      center: {lat: 40.248, lng: -73.580},
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_by_owner.kml',
      preserveViewport:true,
      map: map
    });
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/kml/marineobs_by_owner.kml?_='+ new Date('now').getTime('current'),
      preserveViewport:true,
      map: map
```